# flutter firebase firestore: How to get images stored in array firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display the images with index through the urls stored in Firebase firestore, I am getting the images stored in cloud storage but I don't know how to get the url stored in firebase firestore which is in array. pls help me out as I am only a beginner and learning through internet. Image attached below. [image: "users" then "userid" then "images"]Thanks in advance.

```
List<String> urls = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();

 _getImages();
 
}
```

This is the container where images are displaying through urls stored in cloud storage.

```
                Container(

                  height: 160.0,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0,horizontal: 15.0),

                    child: CustomScrollView(
                      
                      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),


                      slivers: <Widget>[
                        SliverPadding(

                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          sliver:
                          _buildContent(urls),

                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                ),
```

This is method through which I am getting the images stored in cloud storage.

```
_getImages() async {

ListResult _result = await _stoarge.ref().child("images").list(ListOptions(maxResults: 10));
_result.items.forEach((_ref) async {
  String _u = await _ref.getDownloadURL();

  urls.add(_u);
  setState(() {
    print(urls.length);
    print(urls);
  });
});

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your `getImages()` function

```
//First, you must retrieve your document, like this:
DocumentSnapshot firebaseDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('yourDocumentId').get();

//then you need to extract your list, which is in the 'images' field, you can do so like this:
List<String> imagesList = firebaseDoc.data()['images'];

//Now, you have a list, containing the URLs you want.
print(imagesList[0]); //should print the first URL, you can take it from here
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but now I am getting this error. " Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' "

Comment: change it to this:
`List imagesList = firebaseDoc.data()['images'];`

Comment: still same error -- [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'

Comment: sorry to bother you with new queries, now it is printing all the url in console but without the index, which I need at the time to delete image, but still it is not displaying in container, how to get them display and with index?

Comment: You don't need the index, you can just remove the element you want without having to pass the index.

Comment: Or, if your list doesn't have duplications, you can use `list.indexOf[yourelement]`, and you'll get the index

Comment: ok sir, but why it is not displaying on the phone screen, I didn't change any code linked to that.

Comment: Most likely because you didn't tell your Flutter App to show the things you want.